# Turn a Fraction Up and Down but it is Equal to the Original Fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f(10^nd_n+10^{n-1}d_{n-1}\cdots10^1d_1+10^0d_0)=10^nd_0+10^{n-1}d_1\cdots10^1d_{n-1}+10^0d_n$, where $d_i=0,1,6\text{ or }9$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_6=9$, $a_9=6$. For example, $f(1906)=9061$. (This function actually turns the number up and down.)

If integers $p$ and $q$ satisfy $\frac pq=\frac{f(q)}{f(p)}$ (which means turning the fraction $\frac pq$ up and down and that's just equals to $\frac pq$), it's easy to find the two cases of solutions. One is $p=q$, and another is $p=f(q)$. But the third case is difficult to find (and I found it with the help of the computer), which is that p contains only $9$ and $0$ ,and q contains only $6$ and $0$, and $0$s in $p$ and $q$ must be in the same digits. Or oppositely, p contains only $6$ and $0$ ,and q contains only $9$ and $0$. For example, $\frac{9099}{6066}=\frac{9909}{6606}=\frac{f(6066)}{f(9099)}$.

If there is a solution that isn't in the three above cases, post your solution as an answer. If you can prove every solution belongs to the three above cases, post your proof.

Comment: Your last fraction should be $\frac {f(6066)}{f(9099)}$